# SwiftUI - assign Firbase Database output to Data Model

Tags: ios, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

im new to swift and Firebase. And im trying to  understand it.

I have a Cloud Firestore DB, where i store some user data like username and email. Now i want the output of the given User assign to my UserData Model for easy use. i really dont know how to achiev this.

These are my two Files:

```
User.swift

import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore


    struct User {

        var username : String
        var email : String
    }
```

---

```
GetData.swift

        let docRef = db.collection("users").document(Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)

    docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
        if let document = document, document.exists {
            let dataDescription = document.data().map(String.init(describing:)) ?? "nil"
            print("Document data: \(dataDescription)")
        } else {
            print("Document does not exist")
        }
    }
```

The Variable dataDescription is givin me a dictonaryArray, with all the needed values. And now i need to assign that Dictonary to my User.swift struct.

best regards!

fYI: [Firebase Printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbkOJ.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend using Codable where you can. I'm using the `CodableFirebase` Cocoapod to help with Firebase parsing. Below is an example how to use this:

```
    let docRef = db.collection("users").document(Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)
    docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in

        guard let value = document.value, value as? NSNull == nil else {
            return
        }

        do {
            let newValue = try self.decoder.decode(User.self, from: value)
            ///New value created here
        } catch let error {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

You can make this more generic by passing through a class type and having an optional instance returned:

```
    static func item<T: Codable>(_ item: T.Type, docRef: DatabaseReference, completion: @escaping ((Result<T?, Error>)->Void)) {

        docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in

                            guard let value = snapshot.value, value as? NSNull == nil else {
                    completion(.success(nil))
                    return
                }

                do {
                    let newValue = try self.decoder.decode(T.self, from: value)
                    completion(.success(newValue))
                } catch let error {
                    completion(.failure(error))
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Firestore now [officially supports Codable](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/627#issuecomment-545100563) (based on the code `CodableFirebase` contributed). 

The [iOS Quickstart Exampl](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/tree/master/firestore/FirestoreExample) shows how to use this. For example, decoding a document is [pretty straightforward](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/master/firestore/FirestoreExample/RestaurantsTableViewController.swift#L79): `maybeModel = try document.data(as: Restaurant.self)`

Answer (score 0):

try

GetData.swift

```
var user = User()
let docRef = db.collection("users").document(Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)
docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
    if let document = document, document.exists {
        let dataDescription = document.data().map(String.init(describing:)) ?? "nil"
        print("Document data: \(dataDescription)")
        user.username = document.data(["username"]) as! String
        user.email= document.data(["email"]) as! String
    } else {
        print("Document does not exist")
    }
}
```